# single backtick code not shown in jekyll github blog

Tags: github, jekyll, backticks

i'm trying to display a code block with a grey background on sudo visudo and /etc/visudo.
i think it's working on github page, but when take a look in jekyll it is not working as the way i expected.

this is my code in .md file:

````
type `sudo visudo` to enter `/etc/visudo`.

```
User privilege specification  
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL  
hadoop ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL  
sparkuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL  
```
````

[shown in github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEOhA.png)

[shown on jekyll blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c52hF.png)

and my _config.yml file:

```
markdown: kramdown  
kramdown:  
  input: GFM  
  syntax_highlighter: rouge  
  syntax_highlighter_opts:  
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    css_class: 'highlight'
```

what can i do to make a grey background on sudo visudo and /etc/visudo?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What looks like is happening here is that your specific Jekyll theme doesn't put a background behind `sudo visudo` or `/etc/visudo`. Since the font is changing to a monospaced font in your Jekyll example picture, it is properly parsing the markdown, it's just that the theme isn't set to display a background behind it.

Comment: yeah, you're right. haven't thought theme would be a problem. thank you!